# Magento: Bundled Products not showing options

Tags: php, magento

I can't seem to figure out a problem I'm having with a Magento store at www.momuga.tv.

So; the issue is as follows:

```
http://www.momuga.tv/bundle-test-1-dvd.html
```

The product at this link is a bundled product; and it successfully shows all of the bundled products as options. (Bare in mind that we've set the checkbox input boxes to display:none so they won't show up)

However; this product is a duplicate of the above but we get no options showing; we've also got different bundle products; all of which aren't working either:

```
http://www.momuga.tv/bundle-test-1-dvd-2.html
http://www.momuga.tv/young-kids.html
http://www.momuga.tv/robin-williams.html
```

WHAT WE'VE TRIED ALREADY:

1. Reindexed via SSH Deleted index locks; caches and sessions and
   reindexed again...many many times.
2. Duplicated the products; and tried with different simple products
3. Checked the settings of the one that is working with the three other products
4. Turned indexing onto Manual and tried reindexing
5. Nothing in the error or exceptions log to help either.

SOOO; any ideas you guys have as to what could be the cause will be very much appreciated; Google has not been much help on this one and it's too bizarre for us!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out; it was a weird database error caused by a cron job running and then not completing properly.

So not really too surprised I didn't get an answer!!